How to start and keep a Windows service running after Java program exits?
I followed other examples on Stack Overflow that relate to this question, but they only show how to start the service and keep it alive inside the Java program. My question is different. I need to start the service from a Java program and then exit the Java program and have that service to continue running. Then a few days later stop that service from a Java program.
Here is the Java code I'm using to start the service, but as soon as the Java program exits the windows service that it started also exits which is the problem I am trying to solve.
String[] startScript = { "C:/test.exe", "/c", "sc", "start", "Test" };

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startScript);

// java program exits here but service won't keep running

About 5 days later I need to stop the service via some Java code similar to this code example...
String[] stopScript = { "C:/test.exe", "/c", "sc", "stop", "Test" };

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stopScript);

The 'test.exe' is a listen socket server that stays alive accepting connections until stopped. FYI I already have this 'test.exe' installed as a windows service and I see it appear in the Task Manager once started from the Java code above but only for a moment and then it exits once the Java program exits.
How can I keep the 'test.exe' running after the Java program exits?

What is test.exe? Since we don't know what it does, the question is not answerable. Also don't use Runtime to execute a process, use ProcessBuilder. And add error control.

If you're trying to stop a service, there shouldn't be anything before sc

@aled I updated my question with that info. And ProcessBuilder behaves the same way.

Your use of { "C:/test.exe", "/c", "sc", "start", "Test" } is wrong. You're running test.exe as a child process of your Java application (passing the parameters "/c", "sc", "start", "Test" ), not as a Windows service. You need to run sc start test (e.g. {"sc", "start", "test" }, assuming there actually is a Windows service called test.

@Mark Rottevel thanks that worked. I updated my question to address your comment.

Please don't add things like "SOLVED" to a title.

Always check a command at the command line before you try to automate it with some programming language. I told you days ago that you'd got the command wrong

@g00se you told me "if you're trying to stop a service" ... my question stated that I wasn't even able to start the service from Java and keep it running after Java exited. I can't do a stop without doing the start... but I appreciate your help in getting the stop working.

Stopping or starting, either way, the command is sc, to that's how your Java command should start
